# What is the relation between Frey's Curve and Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Can anyone give an overview showing how the elliptic curve $E (a, b) := y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ is associated with the solution of $a^n+b^n=c^n$?

In 1969 Hellegouarch performed the elliptic curves $E (a, b)$, which were later named after Gerhard Frey and were constructed from the solutions of the Fermat equation, he reported on the curves in an article in Acta Arithmetica. I have found the [article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa26/aa2636.pdf) but it is not in English.

I was looking for a document (lecture note, book, blog) that elaborately explains how the elliptic curve $E (a, b) := y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ is associated with the solution of $a^n+b^n=c^n$ and asked it on [mathoveflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350153/134689), I got some documents but I could not understand the whole thing. So, I am asking for help of this forum.

**What I got so far:**

Let $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, $\Delta=(ab)^2+4a^3c-4b^3+18abc-27c^3.$

If $c=0$, then $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$, $\Delta=(ab)^2-4b^3.$

Now the Frey's curve is , $y^2=x(x-A)(x+B)=(x^2-Ax)(x+B)=x^3-Ax^2+Bx^2-ABx.$

Let, $a=(B-A), b=-AB,$ then $\Delta= \{(B-A)(-AB)\}^2-4(-AB)^3= \{(B-A)^2-4(-AB)\}(-AB)^2=(A^2+B^2-2AB+4Ab)(AB)^2=(A+B)^2(AB)^2.$

Now, let, $A=a^q, B=b^q,$ then, $\Delta=(a^q+b^q)^2(ab)^{2q},$ if $a^q+b^q=c^q$ for $q>2$ (this is Fermat's last theorem) then $\Delta=(c^q)^2(ab)^{2q}=(abc)^{2q}.$

Now whats wrong with   $\Delta=(abc)^{2q} ?$

Comment: The curve itself is just based on a proposed set of integers satisfying the equation. The contradiction comes about due to extremely subtle and deep properties of the relationship between elliptic curves and modular forms. There is no way to describe that relationship briefly.

Comment: As stated above, the reasons are very deep. However, if you are willing to assume the $abc$-conjecture then the argument of Silverman *The Arithmetic of ECs* Prop 11.2 shows you why to believe it.

Comment: It's certainly not a simple problem, and there are several key steps from here. First, the fact that the (prime-to-$2$) part of the discriminant is a $q$-th power means that the Galois action on the $q$-torsion points $E[q]$ is [unramified outside $2, q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140696/the-mod-p-galois-representation-of-the-frey-curve-is-unramified-away-from-2).....

Comment: .....Next, [a major paper of Ribet](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/invent_100.pdf) shows that if $E$ is modular, then $E[q]$ is modular of level $2$. Since no weight $2$ level $2$ modular forms exist, $E$ cannot be modular. At this point "all" that remains is to prove that $E$ is modular, which is of course Wiles' modularity theorem.

Comment: Your description of the Frey curves is not quite right - Fermat solutions $a^n + b^n = c^n$ are associated to $y^2 = x(x-a^n)(x+b^n)$. The association is simply that, putting the $a,b$ coordinates of solutions into a curve. The deeper aspect is this curve will then have rather unusual arithmetic; so unusual that it doesn't exist (except for the trivial solutions).